# How to inject Mocked Presenter of Activity in Instrumentation testing with Espresso

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, dagger-2, android-mvp

I have been trying this for a week. And I have crawled every article available but their implementations or examples fall short or stop at the steps of Espresso Tests.

My Android Application follows MVP architecture (And is in Java)

Scenario: [Giving just one example]
I have a `HomeActivity` which gets a `HomePresenter` using Dagger2. (Provides method in the `HomeModule` exposed through a `void inject(HomeActivity activity)` in the `HomeComponent`.

In my espressoTest for `HomeActivity` I would like to inject a mockpresent.
I Have not exposed this dependencies inside an `AppModule` through an `AppComponent`. which most examples on the net do (So they just create a new testApplication and then do the needfull)

I do not want to use the productFlavours way of injecting or providing mockclasses as it doesnt give me control over the `Mockito.when` methods.

So basically. I would like to inject a mockpresenter wherein i can do whatever `Mockito.when()`s on it for the sake of my unit tests in espresso.

## My Code is below.

**HomeComponent**

```
@HomeScope
@Component(modules = HomeModule.class,dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface HomeComponent {
    void inject(HomeActivity activity);
}
```

**HomeModule**

```
@Module
public class HomeModule {

    private final IHomeContract.View view;

    public HomeModule(IHomeContract.View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Provides
    @HomeScope
    public IHomeContract.Presenter presenter(FlowsRepository flowsRepository, UserRepository userRepository, LoanRepository loanRepository) {
        return new HomePresenter(view, flowsRepository, userRepository, loanRepository);
    }

}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class,RepositoryModule.class})
@AppScope
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(App app);

    FlowsRepository flowRepository();
    LoanRepository loanRepository();
    UserRepository userRepository();
}
```

**AppModule**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private Context appContext;

    public AppModule(@NonNull Context context) {
        this.appContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    public Context context() {
        return appContext;
    }
}
```

**App**

```
component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
```

**HomeActivity**

```
HomeComponent component = DaggerHomeComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(((App) getApplication()).getComponent())
                .homeModule(new HomeModule(this))
                .build();
```

Once again. In my tests (espresso) i would like to inject a mockedHomePresenter the set by Mockito. So I can just unit test my views.

Answer (score 8):

The key point in resolving the problem is to have such a *Dagger Module* that provides a mock *Presenter* in `HomeActivity`'s instrumented test instead of the "real" one.

For this the following 2 extra actions need to be done (*you might also want to see an [example](https://github.com/onikx/PagedTextApp)*).

1. Delegate instantiation of *HomeActivity*'s *Component* to some abstraction.
2. Substitute the implementation of the abstraction in instrumented tests to provide mocks.

I'll use *Kotlin* in the example below.

Define the delegate interface:

```
interface HomeComponentBuilder {
    fun build(view: IHomeContract.View): HomeComponent
}
```

Move the `HomeComponent` initialisation from `HomeActivity` to the delegate implementation:

```
class HomeComponentBuilderImpl constructor(private val app: App) : HomeComponentBuilder {

override fun build(view: IHomeContract.View): HomeComponent =
    DaggerHomeComponent.builder()
        .homeModule(HomeModule(view))
        .build()
}
```

Make the delegate be in application "scope" so that you could interchange its implementation for instrumented tests:

```
interface App {
    val homeComponentBuilder: HomeComponentBuilder
    ...
}
```

`App` implementation should now contain

```
class AppImpl : Application(), App {
    override val homeComponentBuilder: HomeComponentBuilder by lazy {
        HomeComponentBuilderImpl(this@AppImpl)
    }
    ...
}
```

Component initialisation in `HomeActivity` looks as follows:

```
(application as App)
        .homeComponentBuilder
        .build(this)
        .inject(this)
```

For instrumented testing create `TestHomeComponent` that extends `HomeComponent`:

```
@HomeScope
@Component(modules = [TestHomeModule::class])
interface TestHomeComponent : HomeComponent
```

where `TestHomeModule` provides a mock *Presenter*

```
@Module
class TestHomeModule {

    @Provides
    fun providePresenter(): IHomeContract.Presenter = mock()
}
```

What's left to do is to make a test delegate implementation

```
class TestHomeComponentBuilderImpl : HomeComponentBuilder {
    override fun build(view: IHomeContract.View): HomeComponent =
        DaggerTestHomeComponent.builder()
             .testTestHomeModule(TestHomeModule())
             .build()
}
```

and initialise it in `TestAppImpl`

```
class TestAppImpl : Application(), App {
    override val homeComponentBuilder: HomeComponentBuilder by lazy {
        TestHomeComponentBuilderImpl()
    }
    ...
}
```

The rest is standard. Create a custom `AndroidJUnitRunner` that uses `TestAppImpl`:

```
class TestAppRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application = Instrumentation.newApplication(TestAppImpl::class.java, context)
}
```

and add it to `app` module `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "your.package.TestAppRunner"
    ...
}
```

Usage example:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeActivityTest {
    private lateinit var mockPresenter: IHomeContract.Presenter

    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(HomeActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mockPresenter = activityRule.activity.presenter
    }

    @Test
    fun activity_onCreate_presenter_should_onViewCreated() {
        verify(mockPresenter).someMethod()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So. Your problem is that you need to create a Module that provides a mock presenter for testing instead of the "real" one.

There is quite a good article on this here: [Testing with Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying, I am aware of this article and approach, but the limitation i have reached is for instrumentation tests. the presenter , for a module, which does not need to exist in the app's component. And Mockito utilization is also redundant if i have to make static (read hard coded) classes/mocks.